# First query result to be modified and used in the second query SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table1 suppose ABC from which I am getting an o/p from a column like 'MYname_GKS_50' . I want only **MYname** part of that result to be used as a condition to fetch another column of different table. 
Suppose If i give columnname = **MYname** from table2.xyz . These 2 queries should be in a single SQL query in OracleDB.
e.g:

- Table1 (col1 , col2)

  col2 has **data**  MYname_GKS_50,MYname_GKS_51, MYname_GKS_52 , Ora_10, Ora_11...

i want col2 results only  the **MYname_GKS**  and **Ora** part  for my search condition , the changing nos are not required.

- Table2 (Col3, col4)

the value from col2 i.e. **MYname_GKS** and **Ora** should be now compared with col3 of table2. 
if it matches, it should give me the col4 of the table2.

Any suggestions gurus!

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: Removed sql-server based off OP asking about OracleDB and column names Ora_10 Ora_11

Comment: Database used is Oracle 11g. Ora_10,11 are simply words i used, it were like suppose Order_detailsversionOne_100056 ,  Order_detailsversionOne_100057, Order_detailsversionOne_100058.. Donot get confused with any ORA errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `like` in joining condition:

```
on t1.col2 like t2.col3||'%'
```

Like here:

```
with table1 (col1, col2) as (
    select 1, 'MYname_GKS_50' from dual union all
    select 2, 'MYname_GKS_51' from dual union all
    select 3, 'MYname_GKS_52' from dual union all
    select 4, 'Ora_10'        from dual union all
    select 5, 'Ora_11'        from dual ),
table2 (col3, col4) as (
    select 'MYname_GKS', 'XYZ' from dual union all
    select 'Ora',        'PQR' from dual )
select * 
  from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.col2 like t2.col3||'%'
```

Result:

```
      COL1 COL2          COL3       COL4
---------- ------------- ---------- ----
         1 MYname_GKS_50 MYname_GKS XYZ
         2 MYname_GKS_51 MYname_GKS XYZ
         3 MYname_GKS_52 MYname_GKS XYZ
         4 Ora_10        Ora        PQR
         5 Ora_11        Ora        PQR
```

There is a risk that table2 contains more then one matching row for instance `MYname` and `MYname_GKS` and I don't know what You want in such situation.

Comment: Seems this query might work On condition . let me try. though i have 10million of data under each column, hopefully i can't do that select statement. Thanks for your update.

Comment: It is not clear. Instead of writing comments which changes requirements please edit your original question, show simplified input data in two tables and required output matching these data.

Comment: My ultimate requirement is COL4 data.. Lets say I have 100 rows under COL2 with myname_1,myname_2, old_1,old_2,old_3,get_4,get_5,look_2,look_99 and so on.  In other Table2, COL3 has data only myname,old,get, look . this column do not have numbers. i want comparison of COL3 each data with COL 2 if it matches , then i should get or select in sql COL4 data of the TABLe2. The ON condition u gave , I need to check. it will work it seems. i have lets say 100 200 diferent names like myname,old,get,look etc.. so i cant use your select condition, where one by one I need to type. not required

Comment: The `with` part is only to mimick your  data. Everything you need to write are last two lines.

Comment: Yeah I got that Stibbons. I will try that once i will be inside network. I was explaining the entire scenario of mine. Just in case anyone doesnot understand it. I will keep everyone posted. Thanks everyone for your notes.